# routes in Bings maps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I used the documentation and I followed all the steps but when I try to implement the code I can't see anything.

```
BingMapsDirectionsTask bingMapsDirectionsTask = new BingMapsDirectionsTask();

// You can specify a label and a geocoordinate for the end point.
GeoCoordinate spaceNeedleLocation = new GeoCoordinate(-33.3935,-070.6215);
LabeledMapLocation spaceNeedleLML = new LabeledMapLocation("camino las rosas,santiago,chile", spaceNeedleLocation);

// If you set the geocoordinate parameter to null, the label parameter is used as a search term.
// LabeledMapLocation spaceNeedleLML = new LabeledMapLocation("Space Needle", null);

bingMapsDirectionsTask.End = spaceNeedleLML;

// If bingMapsDirectionsTask.Start is not set, the user's current location is used as the start point.

bingMapsDirectionsTask.Show();
```

Comment: Your code seems fine. What exactly do you mean my "I can't see anything"? Take a look at this demo if it helps: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7e-otpkZEuo

Comment: Thanks I think it was the windows phone emulator the problem.